# How to add font awesome from node_modules directory using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, frontend, font-awesome

I've installed font-awesome using npm install font-awesome --save-dev, and now Im having trouble including it on my project. Below are my code.

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
            test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|otf)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]',
}
```

**app.scss**

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

**Error**

*ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0
Module parse failed: /ProjectSite/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0 Unexpected character '�' (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reading doing some research I finally solved it by adding **([\?]?.*)$** on the regex part.

```
{
     test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|otf)([\?]?.*)$/,
     loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the npm file-loader package?

`npm install --save-dev file-loader`

I have a webpack example repository in which I include font-awesome. It might help. You can find it [here](https://github.com/JeffGos/jg-webpack-example)

Comment: yes I have installed file-loader but still dont work

Answer (score 0):

with new webpack versions you may wanna try

```
{
    test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|otf)([\?]?.*)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }
    ]
}
```